# os.time prints formatted date rather than number

Tags: lua

I'm just wondering what could be the reason for this line to return a formatted string

```
    print(os.time{year=2018, month=11, day=11, hour=11})
```

returns **2018-11-11 11:00:00**

where if I go to [lua demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) it returns date in numbers

is that a reason because of system difference? What can I do to get these numbers? My main goal is to add certain of days to the date.  In following format :

```
oldDate + (60*60*24*daysToAdd)
```

Comment: Where did you get your Lua interpreter from? Are you sure you haven't redefined `os.time`?

Comment: @lhf I didn't think about it actually. We use in-build lua interpreter that goes with the engine so it must be them that redefined some functions. What a pity. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you still can add days despite of non-standard `os.time`.
Try

```
local dt = os.date("*t") -- today 
print(dt.day, dt.month)  -- 28 nov
dt.day = dt.day + 111    -- add 111 days
dt = os.date("*t", os.time(dt))
print(dt.day, dt.month)  -- 19 mar
```

Does it print March 19 ?

Comment: I found out that they changed standard 'os.date' to have syntax of 'os.ts.date' but it looks like your solution works as well, thank you

Comment: @thedumbone - They've [moved](https://help.interfaceware.com/kb/1330) standard Lua functions to `ts` subtable: `os.time` become `os.ts.time`; new function `os.time` returns userdata.